# Does a deep space network benefit by having a diversity of latitudes?

Tags: deep-space-network, ground-station, site-selection

When placing ground stations for a deep space communications network, there is a well-established benefit to spreading out the stations by ***longitude***.  In particular, having at least three stations separated by 120° longitude ensures that a spacecraft is in the line-of-sight of at least one station at all times.  This is the case for NASA's [DSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network) (Canberra, Australia; Madrid, Spain; and Goldstone, California) as well as ESA's [ESTRACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTRACK) (New Norcia, Australia; Ceberos, Spain; and Malargüe, Argentina).

*Is there also an advantage to having stations at different **latitudes***?  For example, both the NASA and ESA networks have stations in both the northern and southern hemispheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a minority of missions, yes. Most deep space missions stay in/near the plane of the ecliptic so they're visible from a large range of latitudes.

But the [Voyagers are at significant angles](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35896/what-if-the-voyagers-had-remained-within-the-plane-of-the-ecliptic/35911#35911) to the ecliptic, which reduces the amount of time they're visible from wrong-hemisphere DSN stations (or blocks some stations completely, depending on the exact geometry).

[Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)) had an even bigger angle to the ecliptic (inclination 80º).

Comment: There are some relevant Voyager numbers [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35946/12102), but Ulysses is a whole 'nother ball of wax!

Comment: The extreme latitude stations are good for talking/tracking polar orbiting spacecraft.

Comment: Yes, but spacecraft in a polar Earth orbit don't need the DSN and its gigantic deep-space antennas.