# Voyager location

Tags: artificial-satellite, nasa, probe

11/19/2017
Q:Is sun is in the middle of voyager(1&2)?
 I've recorded this data yesterday.
According to Nasa.gov(VoyagerMissionStatus) 
**Distance of Voyager From Earth In Miles**
           1575359 miles (in 24hrs)
**Distance of Probe From Sun In Miles**
           908566  miles (in 24hrs)

Comment: Those are almost certainly distances *traveled* in those 24 hours, not total distance.

Comment: Calculated Data...

Comment: Why "the Distance of SUN" is lesser then "the Distance of Earth"?

Comment: @Astroboy Could you clarify; are you asking *Is the Sun is between Voyager 1 and Voyager 2?*

Comment: @uhoh Is the Sun is between Earth and The Voyager?

Comment: @Astroboy: Because the earth moves at a pretty fair clip (66600 mph) in its own orbit around the sun, and sometimes it moves in the opposite direction from Voyager, so the distance will increase faster than it otherwise would. Right now it's only partly moving away (and partly just moving sideways relative to Voyager), so the difference is considerably less, a bit under 30000 mph.

Comment: @Astroboy There are two different Voyager spacecraft, called *Voyager 1* and *Voyager 2* and they have gone in different directions. See for example [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14317/12102).

Comment: Voyager mission status: https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/

Answer (score 3):

Position of the two Voyager probes:

[image]

(from [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/is-there-any-way-to-find-and-track-pioneer-10-11-and-voyager-1-2))

So they're both in the same general direction seen from Earth, not on opposite sides of the solar system. What you can't see in this image is that both Voyagers are moving out of the plane of the ecliptic ([this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/how-well-can-voyager-1-separate-earth-signals-from-solar-noise-these-days) has a nice animation that shows that), with Voyager 1 going 'up' and Voyager 2 going 'down'.